# Replace array values by $replacements key/value map in PHP

Tags: php

I am having one (associative) data array `$data` with values, and another associative array `$replacements`.

I am looking for a short, easy and fast way to replace values in `$data` using the `$replacements` array.

The verbose way would be this:

```
function replace_array_values(array $data, array $replacements) {
  $result = [];
  foreach ($data as $k => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value, $replacements)) {
      $value = $replacements[$value];
    }
    $result[$k] = $value;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Is there a native way to do this?

I know `array_map()`, but maybe there is something faster, without an extra function call per item?

### Example:

See https://3v4l.org/g0sIJ

```
$data = array(
  'a' => 'A',
  'b' => 'B',
  'c' => 'C',
  'd' => 'D',
);

$replacements = array(
  'B' => '(B)',
  'D' => '(D)',
);

$expected_result = array(
  'a' => 'A',
  'b' => '(B)',
  'c' => 'C',
  'd' => '(D)',
);

assert($expected_result === replace_array_values($data, $replacements));
```

Comment: Can you show an example of `$data`, `$replacements` and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest/least verbose way I can think of:

```
return array_map(function($value) use ($replacements) {
  return array_key_exists($value, $replacements) ? $replacements[$value] : $value;
}, $data);
```

Using `array_map` is basically just looping over the array, which any other base function would also have to do anyway.

Comment: `array_map()` calls a function for each iteration, which adds some overhead (would be curious how much). It is still a correct answer though.

Comment: @donquixote I doubt this would be significant at all, but I may be wrong. Maybe you can run some benchmarks.

Comment: If you have a data-crunching algorithm where this is called a lot, then I bet it will be significant.

Comment: Or if the array is really big.

Answer (score -1):

You can give a try to [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

Comment: `array_replace` replaces values based on their indexes, OP wants them replaced based on their values (unless I misunderstood).